# How to find count of multiple columns in sql group by id?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with schema like below:

```
root
|id
|name
|col1
|col2
|...
|col30
```

Conditions are that multiple rows can have the same name (they're not primary key - the key is the ID). Values in col1-col30 will be some string, or it can have the string "null".

I'm interested in the number of columns filled in for each name.

For example,

if name "`test1`" has `col1-5` filled in a row, and another row has "`test1`" and have `col1, 3, 10, 6` filled in (and the rest of unfilled columns are just string value "null"), "`test1`" should have value `9`.
I'm pretty new to SQL and have been looking this up.. Please help.

Comment: so if the same names have same cols filled multiple times you add them all up? important which ones are filled?

Comment: Sample data would really help.  You need to also realize that SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no ordering unless a column specifies it.  I also removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Yeah if it's the same name, then add them all up. Doesn't matter which ones are filled

Comment: @GordonLinoff Argh I'm trying to do this with spark sql so no idea which db I'll be using.. I think they do take postgresql or ansi sql format

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    CASE WHEN col1_max IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + -- Only include non-NULL values
    CASE WHEN col2_max IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT
        name,
        MAX(col1) AS col1_max, -- Non-NULL values come before NULL
        MAX(col2) AS col2_max
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY name
) src
```

You can add more the rest of the columns to fit your case.

**Updated**
I just realized your NULL case is with a "null" string.  Modified:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    CASE WHEN col1_max IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + -- Only include non-NULL values
    CASE WHEN col2_max IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM (
    SELECT
        name,
        MAX(CASE WHEN col1 = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE col1 END) AS col1_max, -- Non-NULL values come before NULL
        MAX(CASE WHEN col2 = 'null' THEN NULL ELSE col2 END) AS col2_max
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY name
) src
```

Comment: what's the src at the end of the parenthesis?

Comment: `src` is just an alias for the table expression / derived query in parentheses.  It's useful if you are selecting/joining multiple tables and need to qualify column names.  In this case with only one table, it's not useful other than to have proper syntax :)

Comment: Ahh I see. I think this could work but I think I need to sum over all case when clauses.. no?

Comment: Yes, no would need to add in the rest of your `col3, col4...col30` columns in both locations on the query.

Answer (score 0):

First you `unpivot` your table and count those rows that have `not null` values. In `postgres`, you can achieve this with `unnest`. I have only used `col1..7` -- change to upto `col30` in your case

```
WITH t AS(
SELECT id,name,
       unnest(array['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']) AS colname,
       unnest(array[col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7]) AS colvalue       
FROM your_table)
SELECT id, name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN colvalue IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS count_filled
FROM t
GROUP BY 1,2;
```